# Nested lists in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to create JSON to use for a nested list.

I assume I am using incorrect syntax on the second ng-repeat:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="n in navData">Label = {{n.label}}</li>
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="n.children in n">Child label = {{p.label}}</li>
      </ul>
  </ul>
```

When my data model is

```
var nav = [{
        label: 'Pages',
        value: 'pages',
        children: [{
            label: 'Home',
            value: 'home'
        }, {
            label: 'Left Nav',
            value: 'left-nav'
        }]
    }, {
        label: 'Components',
        value: 'components'
    }];
```

All I am getting in the html is the top level:

- Label = Pages
- Label = Components

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outer `li` tag should close after inner li tag with `ng-repeat`. And you should use different var name and slightly different expression (actually you have name your var as `p` `{{p.label}}` somewhere but not in nested loop):

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="n in navData">Label = {{n.label}}<!-- closing li removed //-->
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="p in n.children">Child label = {{p.label}}</li>
      </ul>
    </li> <!-- closing li tag added //-->
</ul>
```

Comment: i was so close.  actually the main issue in my code was my misplaced closing LI tag. I didn't wrap the nested UL.